# Is there still CoverageStack object in GeoTools?

Tags: raster, geotools

This is the first time I'm dealing with Geotools 18. I need to work with a GridCoverage Stack object. I saw that there was one in a very old release (until v2.7.4 [CoverageStack](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/2.7.4/modules/library/coverage/src/main/java/org/geotools/coverage/CoverageStack.java)).

Is there a similar object in the nowadays release?

Comment: What does a CoverageStack do?

Comment: A CoverageStack is an object that stacks several raster objects